# Serving Bookdown from Shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, bookdown

According to the [shiny server docs](https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#r-markdown), an r-markdown with an index (like a bookdown doc) should be served by shiny if its in the /srv/shiny-server/ folder.

I cloned the [sample bookdown example](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo) and mounted it to a shiny server.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:4.0.5

RUN install2.r -e bookdown
```

Docker Compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:

    app:
        build: 
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: bookdown_test
        container_name: bookdown_test
        restart: always
        #user: 'root'
        volumes:
            - ./bookdown-demo:/srv/shiny-server/book
        ports:
            - '80:3838'
```

This should serve the book at localhost/book however I only get a blank page and stdout message:

```
bookdown_test  | processing file: index.Rmd
bookdown_test  | output file: /tmp/shiny/rmarkdown/1dd8e4d901d7b5552128fdca39407670/index.knit.md
bookdown_test  |
bookdown_test  |
bookdown_test  | Output created: section-prerequisites.html
```

The file that it creates is not what it should create either.
[image]

How can I utilize shiny server to effectively serve app documentation? It seems like this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current workflow for providing shiny app docs for a shiny app is to render the docs in the docker build process and copy them into the shiny apps www folder

```
COPY manual /manual

RUN R -q -e "rmarkdown::render_site(input = '/manual/', output_format = 'bookdown::bs4_book', encoding = 'UTF-8')" \
  && mv /manual/_book /root/app/www/manual
```

[Joe Cheng's explanation](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/488#issuecomment-902981165) of why the error occurred